# Bottle Neck is giving me wrong shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to implement my VGG16 model , here is my code:

```
model_vgg = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
train_generator_bottleneck = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)
Found 9741 images belonging to 15 classes.
```

Now i am extracting my feature and saving them

```
bottleneck_features_train = model_vgg.predict_generator(train_generator_bottleneck, 19)
np.save(open(bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_train)
```

Now loading my data

```
train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'rb'))
train_labels = train_generator_bottleneck.classes
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=15)
```

Here i am getting the wrong shape of labels and data

```
print train_data.shape
print train_labels.shape
```

Output:

```
 (9728L, 2L, 2L, 512L)
(9741L, 15L)
```

Why i am getting the wrong shape output please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what do you mean by "wrong" here but I will assume you want the `train_data.shape` to have 9741 samples instead of 9728.

The reason comes from the way `predict_generator` works. You specify an argument here which is `steps=19`. That means that your model will do its prediction on 19 batches of your input data. Now I assume the batch_size of your `train_generator_bottleneck` to be 512, therefore you get 19*512 = 9728 outputs.

If you want to have 9741 outputs, I would try this :

```
bottleneck_features_train = model_vgg.predict_generator(train_generator_bottleneck, 20)
bottleneck_features_train = bottleneck_features_train[:9741]
np.save(open(bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'wb'), bottleneck_features_train)
```

Does this fix your shape issue?